# Yii и Couponic script проблема в рендере скриптов

Tags: yii

Здраствуйте, на фреймворке Yii сделана система Couponic script.
Там используеться функция обратного отсчета с использованием скрипта jquery.countdown. Проблема в том что когда вызываю функцию

```
<?=app()->controller->worklet('deal.timeLeft', array('start' => $data->start, 'end' => $data->end, 'timeZone' => $data->timeZone));?>
```

Данная функция вызывает controller который рендерит скрипт

```
    public function taskRenderOutput()
{
    $this->js();

    $layoutView = $this->end-time() > 86400
        ? $this->counterLayoutFull
        : $this->counterLayoutShort;

    $layout = $this->render($layoutView,null,true);

    cs()->registerScript(__CLASS__, 'var untilDate = new Date('.($this->end * 1000).');
    $("#'.$this->getDOMId().' .timer").countdown({until: untilDate,
    layout: "' . $layout . '", onTick: function(periods){
        $("#'.$this->getDOMId().'").uTimeLeftTick(periods,'.($this->end-$this->start).');
    }});');

    $this->render('timeLeft');
}
```

Но если я делаю несколько вызовов, то он не генирирует скрипт в низу сайта, а скорее всего видит что дубль и убирает. Не знаю как быть, может это особенность Yii или же надо копаться в Couponic script